# Usage of contacts of AD in an Outlook add-in

Tags: c#, .net, contacts, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook Add-in that is using Outlook contacts from local machine and Active Directory to create a special kind of meeting requests. The program is communicating with an external server with a SaaS XML service.

The SaaS service is further making use of the contacts. Contacts to the special meeting are combinations of one or more existing Outlook contacts and they're read with automatic prefilling functionality directly from memory.

**My problem:** Combinations of the contacts for the fast prefilling are saved on the program memory and people having many contacts appear to having huge memory consuming on their Outlooks. You can imagine saving all combinations of one's contacts on the program memory when one contact can have several combinations and all of them are saved separately one by one.

Any out of the box solutions are greatly welcome!

Comment: While writing this question I met a [document](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=25) on the similar issue, but haven't had closer look yet..

Comment: That was about databases and seems to be out of the range of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be attempting to load the entire Active Directory object for the email address.  If that is the case, you can limit what you return in your DirectoryEntry to only the necessary fields.  This will greatly reduce the memory footprint.

Beyond this, you might want to look at using Memory Mapped files to improve your performance:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx

Comment: I am storing to an custom object some combinations of the AD data as well as other sources of contact data. Your solution was about files, right? I would store these to the disc but there the problem is that how to work in environment where you don't have full user rights? Or can the AD be handled as a stream that then can be handled with Memory Mapped files? Or what was the point in your answer?

Comment: There are two different things you are dealing with here - getting the information from Active Directory and then storing (in memory) your list of people to search through.  I was addressing both.  You may want to look at the way you are getting data from AD.  These objects, if left in their default state, are very large because they hold all of the data about the user.  That is one issue.  The second is once you have all of your data in memory, how do you manage it.  This is where Memory Mapped files can come into play.  You will need to so some research to see how best to implement them.